# Registering a Calculator does not work in Spree Edge anymore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calculator, spree

Inside my main Extension I have this standard way of instantiating a Calculator. This module is part of the preinitializing process of Spree :

```
module AgedRevolt
  class Engine < Rails::Engine

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    def self.activate
      Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
        Rails.env.production? ? require(c) : load(c)
      end

      Calculator::PerWeight.register

    end

    config.to_prepare &method(:activate).to_proc
  end
end
```

Then when I run the server I get this:

```
app/models/calculator/per_weight.rb:16:in `register': uninitialized constant Calculator::PerWeight::Coupon (NameError)
```

So I try and run them independently and get this:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :002 > Coupon
NameError: uninitialized constant Coupon
    from (irb):2
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :003 > ShippingRate
NameError: uninitialized constant ShippingRate
    from (irb):3
```

What could that be from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did

In my main extension gem :

```
  def self.activate
    Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
      Rails.env.production? ? require(c) : load(c)
    end
    Calculator::PerWeight.register
  end
```

In my custom calculator:

```
def self.register
  super
  ShippingMethod.register_calculator(self)
end
```